# OpenID Connect for authenticating a web-api

Tags: authentication, api, oauth2, openid-connect, single-sign-on

I want to accomplish the following:

1. Having a web application or mobile app authenticating users using openid connect.
2. Having a REST Api authenticated using openid connect using the same user as for point 1.
3. The user should not have to consent since the API is trusted (but not for SPA's)

For point 1 we have a working proof-of-concept. But for point 2 I am not sure what is the best way (also security-wise) to accomplish that.

Option 1:

- Use the same username and password as for the web application. This means that the username and password need to be cached somehow before accessing the API client side. Aside of the caching this has been proved to work using OAUTH2 only.

This was being accomplished by using:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic <my token>" --data-binary "realm=<mysecretrelam>&grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>&scope=<my scopes>" <my secret openidconnect>/oauth2/access_token
```

- Use the authorization token returned from the OIDC authentication for the website. I did not manage to make this work, which endpoint should be used on the OIDC authentication service to (sort of) SSO the user on the webapi?
- Something else...

Comment: I'm confused by you saying "same username and password as for the web app". Are you using OIDC for authentication, or passwords for authentication? Or both, somehow? Anyhow, the usual solution is to either use the OAuth/OIDC token to authorize/authenticate to your REST API (placing session management largely in the hands of the OIDC authentication server), or use the OIDC token to create a local session for the identified user, and use that session token (whatever type of token you want) to authorize access to the REST API.

Comment: You are using OIDC so what is the purpose of username and password?

Comment: We use OpenID/OAuth2 with username and password to log on the web application. (grant_type=password), I have added it to the question

Comment: This is called [OIDC ROPC which is discouraged](https://www.scottbrady91.com/oauth/why-the-resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-type-is-not-authentication-nor-suitable-for-modern-applications). You are not supposed to know the username and password of the user. Use authorization code flow for web app. For browserless client, you can issue access tokens on request of the user by refreshing the access token in cookies. Then use token introspection to verify the access token sent by REST API clients.

Comment: @defalt, so otions one is of the table in that case. I read the authorization code should be used in that case.

Comment: Yes. Authorization code flow for option 1. Use the refresh token obtained from the auth code flow to issue custom access tokens (by refreshing the access token) to the user which the user can use it in rest api clients. Use token introspection to verify the access token sent by rest api clients. Create a developer settings tab in your web app from where a logged in user can request custom access token for CLI clients.

Comment: @defalt we use a web-applicatie to logon with username and password which gives us an id-token and access-token. How to combine this with the authorization code flow since I do not have a code yet after logging in

Comment: Remove your own login form and add sign in with Google, Apple, etc. buttons. The user will be redirected to their signin page. Check the docs of Google, Apple, etc. OIDC Providers docs to implement authorization code flow backed OIDC.

Comment: I added an extra requirement: no user consent should be involved, at least no manual since it is an API

Comment: OIDC by design involves user consent. The identity provider will ask its user if he wants to allow your web service to access his information like email id and registered name which are given to you in `id_token` if user accepts. When you sign in Google, Google always show the data that the service will have access to. OIDC is used to delegate authority so to protect the user, the identity provider will show these details to the user's knowledge.